# Разница во времени исполнения запроса Oracle/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle

Может кто-то подскажет, в какую сторону смотреть и копать?
Переводим проект с Oracle на PostgreSQL PG. Запрос на тестовой БД исполняется за 600ms на Oracle и 13 минут на PG.
На данных, которых в разы больше, на PG так и не дождались результата (несколько часов). На Oracle было несколько минут. Индексы аналогичны.

Начал разбираться и нашел интересную закономерность -
Запрос типа:

```sql
select t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3,  t1.column2
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.table2_id = t2.id
inner join table3 t3 on t2.table3_id = t3.id
inner join table4 t4 on t3.table4_id = t4.id
```

Отработал на Oracle за 200ms, на PG 2s

Но запрос типа:

```sql
select *
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.table2_id = t2.id
inner join table3 t3 on t2.table3_id = t3.id
inner join table4 t4 on t3.table4_id = t4.id
```

Отработал на Oracle за 3s, а на PG за 180ms.

Совершенно обратная ситуация. Почему это происходит и что нужно учесть при переписывании сложных больших запросов с Oracle на PG?

Comment: Оптимизаторы у разных БД разные и запросы могут выполняться разными путями. Смотрите планы выполнения конкретных запросов на конкретной БД и исходя из них решайте, как их изменить что бы помочь оптимизатору, подсказать более оптимальный путь

Comment: Да, планы запросов разные. Либо full scan всех таблиц. Либо использование индексов. Соответственно обе БД в противоположных ситуациях используют противоположные стратегии. Не понятно почему такой выбор.

Сейчас попробовал на реальном запросе - как только убираешь выборку конкретных столбцов в PG - время резко сокращается

Comment: Попробовал у себя на постгресе, на нескольких таблицах. Если указывать колонки только одной таблицы то в плане выполнения по последней таблице Index only scan, остальные full scan. Что объяснимо, по последней таблице ему только надо проверить что запись существует и сколько их штук. Для `*` то же объяснимо, скан таблицы зачастую быстрее чем поиск в ней записей по индексу, когда фактически нужны все записи